# Creating a new cell, copies previous cell's style in Apache POI..?

Tags: java, apache-poi

In my java class I am declaring cell like:

```
HSSFCell cell = null;
```

And I am using this cell in many places to create a cell and set values, styles. Like:

```
cell = row.createCell(1);               
cell.setCellValue("1234.00");
setCellStyle(currency, cell, workbook);

cell = row.createCell(2);               
setCellValue("2445.00");
```

Now, surprisingly, the first cell's data format is being applied to 2nd cell.
Anyone has any idea?
I expect the 2nd cell's style to be none. And the 1st cell's style should be with the data format applied by setCellStyle() method.
But, actually I am getting both the cell values with data format applied by setCellStyle() method.

setCellStyle() method:

```
public void setCellStyle(String currency, HSSFCell cell, HSSFWorkbook workbook){

        HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = cell.getCellStyle();//I am using cell.getStyle() because the default cell style is not null for a HSSFCell

        HSSFDataFormat dataFormat = workbook.createDataFormat();

        if("GBP".equalsIgnoreCase(currency)){
            cellStyle.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("[$£-809]#,##0_);[Red]([$£-809]#,##0)"));                 
        }else (){
            cellStyle.setDataFormat(dataFormat.getFormat("$#,##0_);[Red]($#,##0)")); 
        }
}
```

Comment: There is no `createCell(String)` method in HSSFRow.

Comment: @rgettman  my mistake, edited

Comment: What is `CUSTOM_STYLE_WITH_DATA_FORMAT`?  Did you verify the data format in Excel with Format -> Format Cells?

Comment: @rgettman Thanks for your quick response. Initially I used "CUSTOM_STYLE_WITH_DATA_FORMAT" just to make the users understand what I need. But it looks like that doesn't enough. So I am showing the actual code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that you've updated your post to show your `setCellStyle` method, I can see the problem.  Every `Cell` starts out with a default `CellStyle`, and they all share the same default `CellStyle`.  When you call `setCellStyle` for the first `Cell`, you are changing that default `CellStyle` that is shared for all cells.  This means that any other cells you create, where you don't set the `CellStyle` have your changes.  Additionally, any other time you call your own `setCellStyle`, it will change the default cell style again.

Instead, create a new `CellStyle` that only that `Cell` will have, using [`Workbook`'s `createCellStyle` method](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#createCellStyle()).

```
HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
```

If you intend to set multiple cells to the same cell style, then you should [reuse the `CellStyle` objects](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CreateDateCells).

> It is important to create a new cell style from the workbook otherwise you can end up modifying the built in style and effecting not only this cell but other cells.

Comment: I have an excel report file with many sheets in it, each sheet contains too many rows and columns. And the data types of the columns are different and need lot of styles (number columns which needs to be formatted in different formats, currency values to be formatted according to the currency name, some strings are bold and some not bold, some have background color, some needs to be italic and etc...). I am doing like the way you said in the answer. But I am trying to apply common things, for example data format by using common method.

Comment: So, if I have 20 columns in a sheet, with 5 different kinds of rows and each cell in a row needs to be formatted in according to the row type, the only solution I have until now is to create each and every required style separately and use. I wonder is this the way we have to deal with apache poi?

Comment: That will work until you run up against the workbook's limit of the number of cell styles.  But I've created many spreadsheets with complicated cell styling in Apache POI, and even though it may be simpler to just re-create the cell style as needed, even if it duplicates one you've already created, it's still better to create the cell styles once, before any processing, then refer to them as needed.

Comment: So, if I have a worksheet that needs 40 different styles, I need to create 40 different styles and use where ever I need in the workbook, without modifying these styles at runtime? What if I need 200 different styles? I am new to apache poi, so want to know

Comment: Yes.  But you can create them lazily if needed.  But if I knew I had 200 different styles that could be applied at any point, dynamically, then I would create some kind of cache object that would `Map` a string with the desired characteristics to a `CellStyle` object.  Create the new `CellStyle` on a cache miss, use the existing one on a cache hit.